# How do I create a Table-valued parameter with no predefined table structure

Tags: parameters, datatable, table-valued-parameters

I want to create a new SQL table from a datatable that has been built within my program.  I simply want to copy the entire table to MSSQL.  From my research I found what appears to be the answer:

> As a side note, in SQL 2008 there is a very easy way to create a table out of a client defined Datatable: pass the DataTable as a Table value parameter, then issue a SELECT * INTO  FROM @tvp, this will effectively transfer the definition of the Datatable and its content data into a real table in SQL.

(Posted by Remus Rusan under this Question --- Creating a SQL Server table from a C# datatable)

What I cannot figure out is how to define the table-valued parameter in SQL server without a table definition.  All the documentation shows defining the `@tvp` with column definitions which of course defeats the purpose of the `SELECT * INTO`.  Unless I am missing something entirely it is not possible to do the above without the SQL server side declaration of `@tvp` and a short sp that calls the SQL statement.